Laravel Livewire: Is there a way to update the JS scripts after updating the component?
I have a component that has a date picker field and a phone mask field. When downloaded, everything works, but when I click save data (update component), the scripts stop working.
I will try to add the following code.
public function hydrate()
{
    $this->dispatch('component-updated');
}

And catch the event in the template.
@push('scripts')
        <script>
            Livewire.on('component-updated', (event) => {
                $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['{{app()->getLocale()}}']);
                $(".datepicker-item").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                });
                $('.phone').inputmask({
                    mask: '(99) 999 99 99',
                    showMaskOnHover: false,
                });
            });
        </script>
    @endpush

Nothing happens. I tried adding setTimeout().
 Livewire.on('changeNumber-updated', (event) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['{{app()->getLocale()}}']);
                    $(".datepicker-item").datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                    });
                    $('.phone').inputmask({
                        mask: '(99) 999 99 99',
                        showMaskOnHover: false,
                    });
                }, 1000)
            });

But I am getting an error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
'setDefaults')

I've been searching for 2 hours and can't find a solution.

Livewire can conflict with other JS libraries (but I suppose you already know this). Can you show the relevant code of the view and the class? Which version of Livewire are you using?

i use version 3

And the relevant code?
